# Web API 404 not found after deploy asp net core web application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-1.1

I Create a solution with vs 2017 that contain two projects:

- 1- Web Api
- 2- Asp .Net Core Web Application that access to WebApi controllers via angular services.

I have one Web Api controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/Client/Get
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        ClientQuery _Query = new ClientQuery();
        List<ClientLisModel> _Results = _Query.GetAll();

        return new JsonResult(_Results);
    }
```

And in my angular service i create a function to access to this controller action:

```
this.getListeClient = function getListeClient() {
             var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/Client/Get'
                })
                    .then(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (msg, code) {
                        deferred.reject(msg);
                        $log.error(msg, code);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

All works correctly when i run my application from vs 2017. . But when i deploy it to MyWebSite in iis 7.5. I have this error:

> GET http://localhost/api/Client/Get 404 (Not Found)

It should look for http://localhost/MyWebSite/api/Client/Get

My Web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Application.UI.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to use config in anuglar module.

So in my angular js module i add this line:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('clientApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'smart-table']);

    angular.module('clientApp').constant('config', {
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:55555',
        baseUrl: '/',
        enableDebug: true
    });
})();
```

And i modify my angular js service like this:

```
angular
        .module('clientApp')
        .service("clientService", function (config, $http, $q) {
            this.getListeClient = function getListeClient() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: config.apiUrl + '/api/Client/Get'
                })
                    .then(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (msg, code) {
                        deferred.reject(msg);
                        $log.error(msg, code);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

After publishing my application i just modify the "apiUrl" in mu angularjs module.